# Call SQL function without creating tables/database

Tags: iphone

Function `HEX` is one of the core functions in [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html)

I would like to call the function from my objective-c code without actually creating a database in my app .. and so on.

What would be the simplest way to call the function with the least addition of classes?

I found lots of functions written in o-c that HEX a string. However, they are not correct as they produce results different from the HEX function of mysql.

Solution: Converting a string to its Hex value

```
+(NSString *) stringToHex:(NSString *)str
{
    NSString *aResult;
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open(":memory:", &database) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *sqlStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select HEX('%@')",str];
        sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                aResult = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            }
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
    return aResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open an in-memory db using sqlite3_open and use that. To do this, open a db with the file name `:memory:` (w/ the colons).

If you only want the hex function, you can also look into the source code of SQLite. It's plain C and in the public domain.

Comment: This might not be the best programming practice (opening a database just to get the HEX of a string) but I believe that since our backend uses the SQL UNHEX function, then this would be the best way to make sure it works without errors. As for the hex function, I was unable to find it in the source of mysql. Actually it is really complicated. Do you think my solution will cause memory errors? I know it might be bad practice.

Comment: I don't think there are any memory issues in your code. If you want to be really sure, use a tool like Instruments or valgrind.

Comment: Also, use SQLite bindings to prevent SQL injection which your code is vulnerable to.

Answer (score 1):

You can easely retrieve HEX string from a NSDate instance:

```
NSString *tokenKey = [[[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
           [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]] 
                   stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just want to convert an NSString to hex.  You could search on here for a better solution, or here's one I just contrived:

```
+ (NSString *)stringToHex:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger hexLength = ([string length] * 2) + 1;
    char *hex = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * hexLength);
    if (hex == NULL)
        return (@"");

    const char *cString = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    for (NSUInteger len = 0, pos = 0; len < [string length]; len++, pos += 2)
        snprintf(hex + pos, 3, "%2x", cString[len]);
    hex[hexLength] = '\0';

    NSString *hexString = [NSString stringWithCString:hex encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    if (hex != NULL)
        free(hex);

    return (hexString);
}
```

Comment: +1 thank you however I no more trust these functions.. I prefer to use the sql HEX especially that the backend is using the same one. Thanks again